# .htaccess Rewrite Rule works on GET but not POST

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am getting some odd behaviour from my `.htaccess` file that I can't seem to solve.

Here is the `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^addpage$ ./addpage.php
RewriteRule ^p/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)/raw$ ./page.php?slug=$1&format=raw 
RewriteRule ^p/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)$ ./page.php?slug=$1
RewriteRule ^add/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)$ ./add.php?u=$1&s=$2
RewriteRule ^all/([0-9]*)$ ./all.php?page=$1
```

When I visit `/addpage` it returns the HTML form to add a new page. But if I make a `POST` request to `/addpage` I get `Forbidden You don't have permission to access /addpage on this server.`.

Why does it work on a `GET` request but not a `POST` request?